# Is it possible to use a MapView without having to extend MapActivity?

Tags: java, android, inheritance, dictionary, android-activity

Currently in my design I've got a base abstract class that all of my activities extend from, however I discovered recently that in order to use a MapView you need to make your activity extend MapActivity.  Since Java does not have multiple inheritance I was wondering if there is any way I can use a MapView without having to recreate my design for my application.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Regards, celestialorb.

Comment: There is a similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/5494307/422931

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is no.  It is not possible to utilize a MapView without extending MapActivity.  As gulbrandr pointed out there is a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5494307/422931), this may be of use for anyone attempting the same thing that I was.

Answer (score 2):

Good question.  I'm interested in what the others have to say.  If the answer is no, you should check out the [OSMDroid](http://code.google.com/p/osmdroid/) project; that's the map I'm using for my application.  It's nice to have the source code to work with...