# How to add MapView in an Activity who already had an "extends"?

Tags: android, api, maps, android-mapview

I'am developping an android application including swipe view with tab.
All page had his own layout, all of that is working great :D.

But I want add to one of this view a MapView ( from Google API ), so i need to extends my MainActivity ( the only one I have ) to MapActivity, but I can't ( nothing wrong here ):

```
 public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements ActionBar.TabListener{
```

so is there a way to manage my MapView from MainActivity ?

thanks a lot :)

( sorry for my poor english syntax )

Comment: There is no `MapActivity` in Maps V2.

Answer (score 3):

Often when you stumble across a problem like this, you need to look at encapsulation rather than extension. Can't you use the MapView as a member variable?

If you check out the [MapView API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/MapView), it states that we must implement the Android life cycle for the MapView in order for it to function properly. So, if you use a MapView as a member variable, you need to override the following methods in your main activity to call the matching methods in the MapView:

```
onCreate(Bundle)
onResume()
onPause()
onDestroy()
onSaveInstanceState(Bundle)
onLowMemory()
```

As an example, your Activity would look like the following:

```
public final class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private MapView mMapView;

    @Override
    public final void onCreate(final Bundle pSavedInstanceState) {
            super(pSavedInstanceState);
            this.mMapView = new MapView(this);
            /* Now delegate the event to the MapView. */
            this.mMapView.onCreate(pSavedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public final void onResume() {
            super.onResume();
            this.getMapView().onResume();
    }

    @Override
    public final void onPause() {
            super.onPause();
            this.getMapView().onPause();
    }

    @Override
    public final void onDestroy() {
            super.onDestroy();
            this.getMapView().onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public final void onSaveInstanceState(final Bundle pSavedInstanceState) {
            super.onSaveInstanceState(pSavedInstanceState);
            this.getMapView().onSaveInstanceState(pSavedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public final void onLowMemory() {
            super.onLowMemory();
            this.getMapView().onLowMemory();
    }

    private final MapView getMapView() {
            return this.mMapView;
    }

}
```

Comment: thanks for you answer, but I thinks it's a bit difficult for me, I don't really see what I must to do... :(

Comment: I've fleshed out the code a little more. Hopefully this'll help.

Comment: Great it's work. But only on my first view ( in first page ) but not in my second page ( crash ) with the same layout :(

Comment: Ah that's great news. I'm really glad I could help. 
Could you now mark your question as answered? :)

Answer (score 0):

The answer is no. It is not possible to utilize a MapView without extending MapActivity. As gulbrandr pointed out there is a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5494307/mapview-without-mapactivity), this may be of use for anyone attempting the same thing that I was.

Comment: So i can use MapFragment ? thanks a lot, I test that right now :)

Comment: `MapActivity` is for Maps V1, which has been deprecated for ~16 months and can no longer be used for new development. Maps V2, the current map API, does not have a `MapActivity` at all, let alone a requirement to use one.